# Wakeonlan only works 5 seconds after shutdown

Tags: networking, power-management, wakeonlan, nic

Any help would be appreciated, I had WOL working on my previous sytem and really would like it to function again.
I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS. I viewed other threads with no solution applied to me

For some reason WOL only works a few seconds after shutdown, I tried both command shutdown and UI.
I also made the file `/etc/defaults/halt` and inserted `NETDOWN=no`

Wakeonlan is enabled in the BIOS (Asrock b450m pro) (allow wake up from pcie devices)


wol is enabled even after reboot:

```
sudo ethtool enp4s0
[...]
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
[...]
```

netplan:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
        enp4s0:
                match:
                        macaddress: a8:a1:59:2c:4f:4e 
                dhcp4: false
                addresses: [192.168.0.99/24]
                gateway4: 192.168.0.1     
                nameservers:
                        addresses: [192.168.0.1]
                wakeonlan: true
```

Comment: When you power off your system the OS no longer has control of the hardware.  If WOL is failing after 5 seconds, check with your computer / motherboard manufacturer for an updated BIOS or check if someone there might be experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing I can find in the manual is the setting regarding wakeup by pcie. All powersaving modes are also turned off, the bios updates list mostly new cpu support and I feel like updating might be a risk since the amd 2400g is not officially supported on the newer  versions (though I'm already running one of the more recent versions since I got the board)

Comment: Also, the OS decides how it shuts down and to what powerstate as wel as what those powerstates mean. The OS has to be configured correctly. But I found the answer to my question and it was more simple than I hoped (see below)

Comment: Not always the case. I have a system here (server) that the OS claims that WoL is supported, but once the system is powered off, the NICs power down too. This is a BIOS setting on mine which is not supported. Now, my second tower (workstation) supports WoL in both the OS and the BIOS and it wakes (powers on) just fine with the magic packet from another system.  So, that statement that you said is not true for all systems, and WoL has gone to BIOS controlled. Glad yours is working.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It seems for WOL to work both the OS and the hardware must agree with eachother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this might seem stupid but I used to be able to unicast the magic packet, at least that's how I remember it.
It was necessary to direct it to the broadcast (.255) address.
Doesn't work: `wol -i 192.168.0.123 a8:a1:59:2c:4f:4e'`
Works: `wol -i 192.168.0.255 a8:a1:59:2c:4f:4e`